# PyQt pushbutton to upload file

Tags: pyqt4, qt-signals

I wanted to implement a pushbutton that allows me to select from various input files and upload the one of my choice. I searched online and put together some code, the problem is, I dont exactly understand how I would implement the fileDialogue within a slot. The code you see inside the slot "on_click" is taken directly from an online example and its not really working. The main issue is that getOpenFileName requires one of the arguments to be "self", Im not sure I know how to use "self" within a PyQt slot. Thanks for the help

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

@pyqtSlot()
def on_click():
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File', '.')
        fname = open(filename)
        data = fname.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(data)
        fname.close()



class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):     #try removing parent=None
                QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
                self.setGeometry(650,300,600,600)
                self.setWindowTitle("Data Viewer")


                quitB = QtGui.QPushButton("QUIT",self)
                uploadB = QtGui.QPushButton("UPLOAD",self)

                hbox = QHBoxLayout()




self.connect(quitB,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),QtGui.qApp,QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))
                uploadB.clicked.connect(on_click(self))

                #add buttons to horizontal box layout
                hbox.addWidget(quitB)
                hbox.addWidget(uploadB)
                self.setLayout(hbox)
def main():
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        mw = MainWindow()
        mw.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code you see inside the slot "on_click" is taken directly from an
>   online example and its not really working. The main issue is that
>   getOpenFileName requires one of the arguments to be "self", Im not
>   sure I know how to use "self" within a PyQt slot.

I think your put together some code is in some class, such as QWidget QMainWindows, etc. But, your can remove it out. It just show in QTextEdit (I think).

Actually, your can implement `getOpenFileName` in your class `QMainWindows` using `QtCore.SIGNAL` connect your `getOpenFileName`. And your can implement with `self`  if your want.

Please see my example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QDataViewer(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        # Layout Init.
        self.setGeometry(650, 300, 600, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Data Viewer')
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton('QUIT', self)
        self.uploadButton = QtGui.QPushButton('UPLOAD', self)
        hBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hBoxLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        hBoxLayout.addWidget(self.uploadButton)
        self.setLayout(hBoxLayout)
        # Signal Init.
        self.connect(self.quitButton,   QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))
        self.connect(self.uploadButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.open)

    def open (self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
        print 'Path file :', filename

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = QDataViewer()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Regards,